# Hitting org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException with Maven 3 on Jenkins v1.461

Tags: jenkins, maven-3, maven-failsafe-plugin

I am trying to switch from Maven 2 to Maven 3 (v3.0.4). The basic command being used is mvn clean verify on jenkins.

When I run a build on jenkins I get the following stack trace on it's console:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

<snip />

Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
mavenExecutionResult exceptions not empty
message : Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.12:verify (default) on project myProject: There are test failures.

Please refer to /home/tc/.jenkins/jobs/myProject-selenium-adhoc/workspace/target/failsafe-reports for the individual test results.
cause : There are test failures.

Please refer to /home/tc/.jenkins/jobs/myProject-selenium-adhoc/workspace/target/failsafe-reports for the individual test results.
Stack trace : 
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.12:verify (default) on project myProject: There are test failures.

Please refer to /home/tc/.jenkins/jobs/myProject-selenium-adhoc/workspace/target/failsafe-reports for the individual test results.
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:79)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:158)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:98)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:64)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:287)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: There are test failures.

Please refer to /home/tc/.jenkins/jobs/myProject-selenium-adhoc/workspace/target/failsafe-reports for the individual test results.
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.reportExecution(SurefireHelper.java:121)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.failsafe.VerifyMojo.execute(VerifyMojo.java:208)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
... 27 more
Maven failed with error.
Sending e-mails to: person@org.com
channel stopped
2012-07-11 21:01:31.564:INFO::Shutdown hook executing
2012-07-11 21:01:31.564:INFO::Shutdown hook complete
Archiving artifacts
Sending e-mails to: person@org.com
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I've tried quite hard searching on the net, trying various pom changes and running maven with -e, -X, -fae etc but nothing seems to allow me shake off this stack trace :( ..  been struggling w/ it for a few days now.

Anybody able to help out with some suggestions and/or pin-pointing the issue w/ a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Please note that the project is organized as:

```
Parent pom
|
----------> module 1
----------> module 2
----------> ...
----------> module 6
```

where module 6 corresponds to myProject above and it has dependencies on some libraries (i.e. module1, module2 etc).

The parent pom has:

```
<reporting>
  <plugins>
      { several plugins including maven-dependency-plugin, maven-project-info-reports-plugin, cobertura-maven-plugin, maven-surefire-report-plugin (v2.12) 
       and maven-surefire-report-plugin (v2.12) specifically w/
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <id>integration-tests</id>
            <reports>
              <report>failsafe-report-only</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
      }
  </plugins>
<reporting>
```

and

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        {several plugins including maven-surefire-plugin, maven-surefire-report-plugin (v2.12), maven-assembly-plugin, maven-release-plugin (v2.3.2)
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        {several plugins including maven-site-plugin (v3.1), maven-compiler-plugin (v2.5.1), maven-release-plugin (v2.3.2)
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Please also note that I am seeing the problem exactly when there are test failures i.e. I would like to get a clean (no stack traces et all) console output when there is a test failure. In fact during my above mentioned troubleshooting I actually setup an (intentionally) failing test. Also when I look at '/home/tc/.jenkins/jobs/myProject-selenium-adhoc/workspace/target/failsafe-reports' the failsafe reports/test failure details output looks good i.e. I see my expected test failure screen capture (custom logic in our framework) AND various summary/reports like emailable-report.html with correct contents.

Thank you !

Comment: Have you checked the mentioned folder: /home/tc/.jenkins/jobs/myProject-selenium-adhoc/workspace/target/failsafe-reports what it contains? Do you have integration tests? If you i would check the reports which has failed.

Comment: @khmarbaise: Sorry, I forgot to mention in the original post that I am seeing the problem exactly when there are test failures i.e. I am trying to get a clean (no stack traces et all) console output when there is a test failure. In fact during my above mentioned troubleshooting I actually setup an (intentionally) failing test.

Also when I look at ...../target/failsafe-reports the failsafe reports/test failure details output looks good i.e. I see my expected test failure screen capture (custom logic in our framework) AND various summary/reports like emailable-report.html with correct contents.